# Get multiple users' data and also one row from another table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

I'm trying to make a complex query to retrieve the admin's, user's row and also, the user's termination row from MySQL.

`users` table fields I want to get: `id` (ai), `username` (for the terminated user), `display_name` for the admin's name, and `serial` to get the user's row and everything else.

`terminations` table has the following structure, but I want to get all of the fields in the query.: `id` (ai), `user` is the id of the terminated user, and the `admin` field is the admin's id who terminated the user.

I tried to achieve a result something like this:

```json
{
   "admin": "admin's display name", 
   "user": {
       "id": 1, 
       "username": "johndoe"
   }, 
   "term_details": {
       "id": 1, // `terminations` auto-increment primary key
       "reason": "reason" 
       // etc from the `terminations` table...
   }
}
```

I tried to make the query myself in one, but with no success. (and I didn't wanted to run multiple query lookups for obvious reasons.) (the `?` is the serial itself which the API I use sanitize and insert into the query.)

```sql
SELECT 
   u.id, 
   u.display_name,
   t.*
FROM 
   terminations t
LEFT JOIN 
   users u
ON 
   u.id = t.user
AND u.serial = ?
WHERE
   t.state = "active" AND 
   t.expire_date > NOW()
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: You havent shown serial as a field.